# Coffescript creating a hashtable

Tags: coffeescript

In the following code segment I'm trying to create a hashtable with a single key named "one" and push the same value "ted" into an array.

```
out = {};
for i in [1..10]
  key = "one";
  if(key not in out)
    out[key] = [];
  out[key].push("ted")
  console.log("pushing ted");

console.log(out);
```

What am I missing? It seems that the output is:

```
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
{ one: [ 'ted' ] }
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
pushing ted
{ one: [ 'ted','ted','ted','ted','ted','ted','ted','ted','ted','ted' ] }
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u4wpg4ts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoffeeScript's `in` keyword doesn't mean the same as it does in JavaScript. It will check for the presence of a value rather than of a key.

```
# coffee
if (key not in out)
```

```
// .js (roughly)
indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;

if (indexOf.call(out, key) < 0)
```

Since the key (`"one"`) is never present in the Array as a value (`"ted"`), the condition always passes. So, the array is being replaced and reset to empty before each `.push()`.

CoffeeScript's [`of` keyword](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) will instead check for the key's presence, which should only pass the first time:

```
# coffee
if (key not of out)
```

```
// .js
if (!(key in out))
```

Comment: You could also `out[key] ?= [ ]` or `out[key] ||= [ ]` instead of the `if`. Or even `(out[key] ?= [ ]).push('ted')` or `(out[key] ||= [ ]).push('ted')`.